# How to download image file by force download

Tags: php, download

I am trying to download image file in CI but getting error when I open download image file. Need help :(

```
$file_name = $_GET['file_name'];
            $file_path =  "./ups_printimages/".$file_name;
            if(file_exists($file_path))
            {
                $this->load->helper('download');
                $data = file_get_contents($file_path); // Read the file's contents
                $name = 'ups_label.png';
                force_download($name, $data);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "file does not exist";
            }
```

Comment: You need to send the correct headers for the file.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Error : Image cant open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GOD. Found out the solution :)

```
if(!file)
    {
         File doesn't exist, output error
         die('file not found');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use header to force download. Use the code below

```
 $file_name = $_GET['file_name'];
                $file_path =  "./ups_printimages/".$file_name;
                if(file_exists($file_path))
                {
                 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_name) . "\""); 
    readfile($file_path); 
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "file does not exist";
                }
```

Hope this helps yoiu

Comment: I think I am giving $file_path wrong
$file_path =  "/var/www/vhosts/cubixcube.com/httpdocs/web/instawhelmed/images/".$file_name;

Please correct me.

Comment: $file_path shouldn't be like that. use absolute url like $filepath="http://yoursitename.com/images/".$file_name;